# What does two sets of list brackets placed together mean in python?

Tags: python, list

For example in python:

```
employees[x][i] = float(employees[x][i])
```

Comment: `employees[x][i]` represents a value,, this syntax will just convert your value to `float` and store it back...

Comment: @dallen: It's hard to search "multi-dimensional array/list syntax" when you don't know it's about multi-dimensional array/lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two brackets mean you're accessing an element in a list of lists (or dictionaries)

So in this example, it might look something like this

```
In [17]: employees = {'joe': ['100', 0], 'sue': ['200', 0]}
In [18]: x = 'joe'
In [19]: i = 0
In [20]: employees[x][i]
Out[20]: '100'
```

Comment: so if i=3, and x=4, you are accessing the fourth element in the third element,which is also a list, in the list employees?

Comment: @usmcs: Note that dictionary vs. list is determined by the type of the `employees` or `employees[x]` object, not by whether the thing inside the brackets is a string or an integer. Integers can be dictionary keys, but strings cannot be array indexes.

Comment: @GregHewgill Yes, that was a sloppy statement on my part, thanks for the clarification.  ShaltNot: I think you have it backwards.  In this example, x=4 would be the 4th element of employees and i would be the 3rd element of employees[x]

Answer (score 3):

Like most languages, it refers to an element in a multidimensional list:

```
l = [[0,1,2,3], [1,1,1,1]]
l[1] == [0,1,2,3]
l[1][2] == 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I put in extra parens to show how this is evaluated

```
(employees[x])[I] = float((employees[x])[i])
```

and an example

```
>>> foo = dict(name="Foo", salary=10.00)
>>> bar = dict(name="Bar", salary=12.00)
>>> employees = dict(foo=foo, bar=bar)
>>> employees
{'foo': {'salary': 10.0, 'name': 'Foo'}, 'bar': {'salary': 12.0, 'name': 'Bar'}}
>>> employees['foo']['name']
'Foo'
>>> employees['bar']['salary']
12.0
```

employees could also be a list (or any other kind of container)

```
>>> employees = [foo, bar]
>>> employees
[{'salary': 10.0, 'name': 'Foo'}, {'salary': 12.0, 'name': 'Bar'}]
>>> employees[0]['name']
'Foo'
>>> employees[1]['salary']
12.0
```

Answer (score 2):

**Syntax meaning of [] in python:**

In python, [] operator is used for at least three purposes (maybe incomplete):

1. define in literal an array, like xx = [0,1,2,3]
2. array element indexing, like x1 = xx[1], which requires index be integer or evaluated to a integer
3. dictionary member retrieval, like s = person['firstname']  // person = {'firstname':'san', 'lastname':'zhang'}, in this case, the index can be anything that a dict tag can be

Thing goes complex when embedding [] in [] or [] next to [], see examples below:

```
matrix = [[0,1],[2,3]]
e01 = matrix[0][1]

people = [{'fname':'san','lname':'zhang'}, {'fname':'si', 'lname':'li'}]
last1 = people[1]['lname']
```

[[]] and [][] are reciprocal to each other.